# Azure Data Explorer: Continuous Export with Managed Identity

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to setup a continues export in Azure Data Explorer by following [these instructions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/create-alter-continuous#continuous-export-with-managed-identity)

I run this query

```
.create-or-alter continuous-export MyExport
 over (table)
 to table externaltable
 with
 (intervalBetweenRuns=1h, 
 forcedLatency=10m, 
 sizeLimit=104857600)
<| table
```

and get the following error

```
Error: continuous export to external tables with impersonation requires setting the 'managedIdentity' property in the continuous export configuration. See https://aka.ms/continuousExportWithManagedIdentity for more information.
```

The instructions say to do the follwing

> In order to use Continuous Export with Managed Identity, please add the AutomatedFlow usage to the Managed Identity policy

But I cant figure out how I am supposed to do that. Is AutomatedFlow a role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which managed identity to use in the continuous export - please see the `managedIdentity` property in the [`.create continuous-export` properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/create-alter-continuous#properties). See more information in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/managed-identities-overview#use-in-supported-workflows) about using managed identities in automated workflows.